# EF Optional Relationships / Nullable / Navigation Table

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, entity-framework-core, identity, blazor-boilerplate

I solved this, answer below.

I am new to EF and having a lot of difficulty trying to get an optional relationship. I am looking to have a relationship where I have ApiLogItem Model with an UserId property which can be null / anonymous user or a logged in user to track all Api calls. The goal is to have Existing Users who do some create a new object to be linked to that object. I do not want to create new Users every time a new ApiLogItem is created.

I have tried a dozen variations with virtual / foreign key attributes and I am stumped. It works great for null / anonymous user but once I attach an actual user to the ApiLogItem it will not insert. I get this error:

> {"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_AspNetUsers'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'dbo.AspNetUsers'. The duplicate key value is
>   (09c0d2e2-b003-4be8-a62a-08d7268af58e).\r\nThe statement has been
>   terminated."}

I have tried following this tutorial but alas no luck.
https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/conventions/one-to-many-relationship#targetText=EF%20Core%20will%20create%20a,public%20class%20Author

```
public class ApiLogItem
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Method { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(45)]
    public string IPAddress { get; set; }

    public Guid? UserId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>
{
    [MaxLength(64)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(64)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public List<ApiLogItem> ApiLogItems { get; set; }
}
```

Error happens when I want to create a new ApiLogItem:

```
        using (ApplicationDbContext _dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext(_optionsBuilder.Options))
        {
            _dbContext.ApiLogs.Add(apiLogItem);
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
```

I have reviewed several other stackoverflow issues and none seem to fix. You can find the repository here:

https://github.com/enkodellc/blazorboilerplate

Comment: I don't know much about EF (also starting with it :)) But maybe you can remove the Guid. I think EF will handle it, so an object should be sufficient. And also change List<ApiLogItem> to ICollection (I always see ICollection instead of list)

Comment: Where in the repository is the ApiLogItem being created? What is in apiLogItem?

Comment: ApiLogItemService, just think of it as a generic widget and it may or may not be assigned to a user.

Comment: You need to `Find` the ApplicationUser and add that to the apiLogItem. All you have at the moment is a Guid that gets stored as a UserId. There is no reference to an existing User. Add a line at the top of your `using` block for `_apiLogItem.User = _dbContext.ApplicationUser.Find(apiLogItem.Guid);` [edit: that might need to be an IdentityUser]

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `applicationDbContextSeed.SeedDb();` in your `Startup` class each time you run, and in your `SeedDb` method, you are adding a user with a static id `09C0D2E2-B003-4BE8-A62A-08D7268AF58E`.

The first time you run, it will create that user; the second time, it will fail because that user (with that id) already exists.

Comment: Thanks for the respons but if you remove the "seed" functionality and try to create a new ApiLogItem with an authenticated user it errors. I don't want to create new Users every time a ApiLogItem is created. I just want that to have the UserId stored with that item so there is a relationship if there is a user logged in.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It needs a virtual in the parent and just the id in the child. I need to learn more about EF as it is not intuitive to me. Will post a better answer later today after testing.

```
   public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>
    {
        [MaxLength(64)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(64)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public ICollection<ApiLogItem> ApiLogItems { get; set; }
    }



public class ApiLogItem
    {
        [Key]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int StatusCode { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Method { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(45)]
        public string IPAddress { get; set; }

        public Guid? UserId { get; set; }
    }
```